# How do I displaying large amounts of boolean values in PostgreSQL 9.1.9 without causing eye strain?

Tags: postgresql

How do I display large amounts of boolean values in PostgreSQL 9.1.9 without causing eye strain?

The issue I have is that various PostgreSQL clients display boolean values as t/f, and when looking at a the data it can be difficult to distinguish the values:

[image]

Comment: It's not "Postgres" displaying `t` and `f`  it's the SQL client you are using. Maybe you can configure that application to display it differently.

Comment: I think you mean "PgAdmin-III", not "PostgreSQL" its self. It's up to the client app to choose how it formats booleans.

Comment: @CraigRinger and a_horse_with_no_name True, however I've found that it's not localized to PgAdmin, hence the generic PostgreSQL, but your point is well made :-).

Answer (score 3):

Playing with casting, you can cast the boolean value as `::text` to get its text value of true or false which outputs (the equally as bad):

[image]

or to resolve the issue, use case statements:

`CASE WHEN dt.x12_940 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE '' END AS x12_940,`

to output:

[image]

Comment: If you need support null values in your booleans as well, you could output an HTML table which used color coding to convey true/false/null.